# Tunnel port (service) out of externally inaccessible network

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am helping with the administration of a private network and I would like to expose some services (for example SSH with local port forwarding would be great). Unfortunately I probably won't be granted access to install any port forwarding in the router. What I can do though is install arbitrary hardware (any kind of computer, Raspberry Pi, etc.).
To get around this very issue I thought of implementing some sort of port forwarding from the closed network to I network I control (like forward port 22 to my network and from there access the "inaccessible" network via SSH and do some local port forwarding, provide a port for VPN, anything). Yet this seems very error-prone to me, as I would need to implement some cron job to check for an outgoing connection or establish one is required.
Are there other ways? Is what I imagined common in any case?
Thank you for your help.

EDIT

Today I read something about routers with client VPN-capabilities - would that work?
I thought of implementing a VPN somewhere I have full control and then force the client VPN router to connect and so give me access to the hosts I would like to reach remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement a couple of years ago. I solved it with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is designed to be scheduled by cron as often as is required
# If STARTFILE exists, it will start/restart the connection
# If STOPFILE exists, it will stop the connection
# If PORTFILE exist, makes sure the tunnel is started, to survive restarts
#
# PORTFILE will always contain the port number on the remote host that the SSH connection is tunneled to
#
# This utilizes the control socket option of SSH to control the tunnel

# Base name, used by other variables
NAME="ssh_tunnel"

# Create this file to start the server
STARTFILE="/etc/$NAME/$NAME.start"

# This file will contain the port number on the remote server to connect to to access the tunnel
PORTFILE="/etc/$NAME/$NAME.port"

# Create this file to stop the server
STOPFILE="/etc/$NAME/$NAME.stop"

# The user and host to connect the tunnel to
REMOTE="user@hostname"

# The private key of the user on the remote server to create the tunnel to
KEYFILE="/etc/$NAME/.ssh/$NAME"

# The control socket of the SSH connection
SOCKET="/var/run/$NAME.socket"

# First port to try and listen on at remote host
LISTEN=9000

# Last port to try and listen on at remote host
MAXPORT=9999

SSH=$(which ssh)

# We need to run as root, otherwise it will fail
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Must be run as root!"
    exit 1
fi

# Make directory if if doesn't exist
if [ ! -d "/etc/$NAME" ]; then
    mkdir "/etc/$NAME"
fi

# Starts the tunnel and updates the control files
start_tunnel() {
    # Remove port file, since it is outdated, if it exists
    if [ -f ${PORTFILE} ]; then
        rm -f ${PORTFILE}
    fi

    # Start tunnel and wait 2 seconds.. It the tunnel isn't up, then the port is busy (or the public key is foobar)
    while true; do
        ${SSH} -M -S ${SOCKET} -2 -4 -C -f -N -i ${KEYFILE} -o CheckHostIP=no -o KeepAlive=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o BatchMode=yes ${REMOTE} -R $LISTEN:localhost:22
        sleep 2
        check_tunnel && break
        set LISTEN=LISTEN+1
        if [ $LISTEN -eq $MAXPORT ]; then
            # No ports available (or more likely, the public key is incorrect)
            exit 1
        fi
    done
    echo ${LISTEN} > ${PORTFILE}

    # Remove startfile, since the process is now started
    if [ -f ${STARTFILE} ]; then
        rm -f ${STARTFILE}
    fi

}

# Stops the tunnel and cleans up the control files
stop_tunnel() {
    # Remove portfile and stopfile if they exist
    if [ -f ${PORTFILE} ]; then
        rm -f ${PORTFILE}
    fi
    if [ -f ${STOPFILE} ]; then
        rm -f ${STOPFILE}
    fi
    ${SSH} -S ${SOCKET} -O exit ${REMOTE} > /dev/null 2>&1
}

# Check if the tunnel is up
check_tunnel() {
    if [ -e ${SOCKET} ]; then
        (${SSH} -S ${SOCKET} -O check ${REMOTE} 2>&1 | grep -q "running") && return 0
    fi
    return 1
}

# Use a lock file so only one instance is running
(
    flock -n 9 || exit 1

    if [ -f ${STARTFILE} ]; then
        # Restart if running, otherwise just start
        check_tunnel && stop_tunnel
        start_tunnel
    elif [ -f ${STOPFILE} ]; then
        # Stop if running
        check_tunnel && stop_tunnel
    elif [ -f ${PORTFILE} ]; then
        # The tunnel should be running, might not be after a reboot, for example
        check_tunnel || start_tunnel
    fi

) 9>/var/run/$NAME.lock
```

The script is designed to be scheduled as a cron job (in my case, every minute).
It check for the existence of the file specified in the `STARTFILE` variable. This was created via a web interface, but it should be quite easy to modify this script to suit your needs. The reason for the web interface control is that the customer perhaps doesn't want to have a permanent backdoor into their network.. :)
Unfortunately, I can't share the web part, since that is part of a much larger project.

Anyways, what you must configure to get this to work is to configure the `REMOTE` and `KEYFILE` variables so it points to a valid user/host and private key. The rest is pretty optional. 
After that, just create the `STARTFILE` and run the script (or schedule it via cron) and the tunnel should start up.

Say that you are running the script on server `A`, and `REMOTE` is set to `user@B`. If the contents of `PORTFILE` on `A` is `9000`, you should be able to login to server `A` via `B:9000`, using any valid user from server `A`.

I hope this all makes sense..

Comment: Thank you - looks good what you submitted. I'll give it a shot ASAP.